# How can I translate all values in an array with Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm indexing logs in ELasticsearch through Logstash which contain a field with an array of codes, for example:

```
indicator.codes : [ "3", "120", "148" ]
```

Is there some way in Logstash to lookup these codes in a csv and save the categories and descriptions in 2 new fields such as `indicator.categories` and `indicator.descriptions`.

A subset of the csv with 3 columns:

```
Column 1 => indicator.code
Column 2 => indicator.category
Column 3 => indicator.description
```

```
3;Hiding;There are signs in the header
4;Hiding;This binary might try to schedule a task
34;General;This is a 7zip selfextracting file
120;General;This is a selfextracting RAR file
121;General;This binary tries to run as a service
148;Stealthiness;This binary uses tunnel traffic
```

I've been looking at the csv filter and the translate filter, but they do not seem to be able to lookup multiple keys.

The [translate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html#plugins-filters-translate-source) seems to work only with 2 columns. The [csv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-separator) seems unable to loop through the `indicator.codes` array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Ruby filter to loop over the indicator.codes and compare them to your data you retrieved from the csv.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/8.1/plugins-filters-ruby.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont know Ruby that well.